# Java. How to set what a method can take as input from a given list (within the method)

Tags: javafx, method-parameters

Is it possible to build a method that only accepts values from a given list of options? Something with a "behavior" similar to the setBackground method, which start displaying a default,

```
BorderPane bP = new BorderPane();
bP.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
```

My goal is to build a factory class, which has a method that takes in either A, or B, or C and returns corresponding objects. The final result of what I am looking is would be something like:

```
MyObject square = new MyObjectFactory(SQUARE)// square is default and is added automatically to the method.
MyObject circle= new  MyObjectFactory(CIRCLE);//user gets a list of SQUARE, CIRCLE, or TRIANGLE...
```

I tried to look on Stackoverflow for similar questions, but I am not even sure what the feature I am looking for is called to start with. So I am describing the "behavior", sort of.

Is there a way to make such a thing in JAVA, or is it only a JAVA "thing"? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you a really looking for... regarding factories: I would build a factory called using: MyObjectfactory.make(ObjectType.CIRCLE) to separate the factory implementation from the Object implementations. If you use new MyObjectFactory(..) all Objects have to have the base class MyObjectFactory. I do not like that dependency, it reduces your freedom of potential object implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am still in my early learning/experimentation with factories. What I am building is shapes of variant properties.  all of them do similar things but with some slight variations, thus I thought of a factory. Currently they all extend an abstract shape class so that I can run general methods on all while be able to do some specialized ones for each based on What variation they belong to. Not sure if  I am using the right strategy. Any feedback is welcome. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a possible factory pattern for custom graphic objects:

```
enum ObjectType { CIRCLE, SQUARE };

public class MyObject extends Group {
}

public class MyCircle extends MyObject {
    public MyCircle() {
        getChildren().add(new Circle(12));
    }
}

public class MyRectangle extends MyObject {
    public MyRectangle() {
        getChildren().add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 18, 18));
    }
}

public class MyObjectFactory {
    static MyObject make(ObjectType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case CIRCLE: return new MyCircle();
            case SQUARE: return new MyRectangle();
            default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported type: "+type);
        }
    }
}

void testFactory(VBox box) {
    MyObject circle = MyObjectFactory.make(ObjectType.CIRCLE);
    MyObject square = MyObjectFactory.make(ObjectType.SQUARE);

    box.getChildren().addAll(circle, square);

}
```